# Implement JWT in Django with gRPC

Tags: django, authentication, grpc, grpc-python

I read [`gRPC` documentations](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/) but it was not clear for me.

In `JWT` requests (`REST`) we always send the token with each request, but what is authentication in `gRPC`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As gRPC is sent over HTTP/2, the tokens are sent as HTTP/2 headers. Typically in Python you add the token as a metadata header and then it will be converted into  HTTP/2 on the wire.

see this sample https://github.com/raylenmargono/gRPC-Python-JWT-Auth-Example

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for an example. I'll check.

Comment: Thank you.It was very helpful for me. I have put my implementation experience [in this repository](https://github.com/realsaeedhassani/django-grpc-example) and will update it.